# AppDomain.CreateDomain causes Access Violation

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, mono, appdomain

I'm making a plugin loader for Unity game (Subnautica). The loading mechanism itself works fine but I want to load the assemblies into a separate app domain so I can unload them at runtime too. 
However, calling `AppDomain.CreateDomain(string)` crashes Unity, leaving an error log with

> Unknown caused an Access Violation (0xc0000005)
>     in module Unknown at 0033:049f7717.
>   ...
>   Read from location 00000000 caused an access violation.

and the log the game produces with

> 0x0000000005048C6D ((<unknown>))
>   ERROR: SymGetSymFromAddr64, GetLastError: 'The specified module could not be found.'
>   ERROR: SymGetModuleInfo64, GetLastError: 'A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.'

I have tried injecting the code that calls `AppDomain.CreateDomain` into the game's code directly and I tried injecting code that loads the dll that calls `AppDomain.CreateDomain` using `Assembly.Load`, both methods crash with the same message.
Unity version is 5.4.4f1, I'm on Windows 10 and the assembly that calls `AppDomain.CreateDomain` uses .net 3.5. [This](https://gist.github.com/thijmen321/7bf2dc8644a2593d8f6f8bcd1d1b4de6) is the error.log created by Unity and the stack trace from output_log.txt created by Subnautica.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing Unity to crash?

PS, I know with certainty that `AppDomain.CreateDomain` is causing the problem.